# Tricky Graph Theory Puzzle

Tags: graph-theory

I ran into an intriguing puzzle on Reddit that I thought could use some attention.

You start with a 3x3 grid labeled with numbers 1-9 like this:

$$ 1 \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }2\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }4
\\ 5 \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }6\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }8
\\ 9 \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }3\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }7$$

To complete the puzzle, you must connect directed edges between the numbers so that:

1. The numbers connect in order from 1-9. There can be intermittent numbers when connecting them. For example, some puzzle may have the solution: **1**, 3, **2**, 9, 4, **3**, 9, **4**, 8, **5**, 7, 8, **6**, **7**, **8**, 2, **9**.
2. The edges cannot overlap each other.
3. The vertices (the numbers) can have multiple edges connecting to it.
4. You cannot go back over edges (no overlaps).

Here's a picture of a completed puzzle:

[image: Solved Puzzle]

I have a couple of question relating to this problem:

If there are impossible puzzles, then what criteria determines if a puzzle is unsolvable? If I were to make it 4x4 or 5x5 or NxN, would the criteria extend to those? What proportion of puzzles for an NxN puzzle are solvable.

Here's the link to the Reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/8b032u/need_help_for_an_eulerian_path_game_i_made/

Comment: Can you link the source on reddit?

Comment: Sorry I will, I'll make sure later, I can't currently though.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, every puzzle of this type is solvable. All that is required is a Hamiltonian cycle on the $n$x$n$ king's graph, which always exists.

Comment: For instance, on the first example grid, take $1 \to 2 \to 4 \to 8 \to 7 \to 3 \to 9 \to 5 \to 6 \to 1$. This satisfies all the edge relations, then **1**,**2**,4,8,7,**3**,9,5,6,1,2,**4**,8,7,3,9,**5**,**6**,1,2,4,8,**7**,3,9,5,6,1,2,4,**8**,7,3,**9** works.

Comment: Why not just put directed edges from 1 to each number and back again?  Or is this what is meant by "edges cannot overlap"?  (I took that to mean that we are looking for a planar graph, i.e. edges cannot cross, but perhaps I am misinterpreting the puzzle?)  Also, in the solution provided, why can't we take $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 4 \to \dotsb$?  I can draw an edge from 5 to 6 and an edge from 6 to 7 without breaking planarity, then eliminate a bunch of redundant edges...  I'm very confused about what it is that I am meant to be doing...

Comment: It looks like there's a condition imposed on the grid structure such that there can only exist edges between vertices "adjacent" in the grid (including diagonals), so in the completed solution, there can't be an edge between $2$ and $7$.

Comment: @B.Mehta I should specify, but edges cannot overlap with each other. That's why there seemed to be more edges than need. I fixed my question to express that, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Can the same edge be used more than once in the final solution? (Can I go from $1 \to 2$ at the beginning, if they're adjacent, then return to $1$ and take the edge $1 \to 2$ again?) If so, then B.Mehta's comment above solves the problem, and they should be encouraged to write it up as an answer; if not, things get more complicated.

Comment: @MishaLavrov It cannot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Condition 4: Not being allowed to go back over edges definitely changes the complexion of the problem. In fact, for ALMOST ALL numberings of an $n \times n$ grid as $n$ gets large, such a completion of the puzzle is impossible.

Why? The resulting digraph on the $n \times n = n^2$ vertices (vertices here taken as points on the grid) would be planar due to Condition 2. This would imply for some subset $S$ of $\frac{n^2}{2}$ vertices of the digraph, then for some  $R$ no more than $4n$, there are exactly $R$ edges leaving $S$. (Theorem of Lipton-Tarjan I believe). However, [one can check that] for $n$ sufficiently large, a random bijective numbering $\cal{N}$ of the $n \times n$ vertices of the grid (where the numbers used are $1,2,3,\ldots, n^2\}$), would be such that there are many more than only $4n$ integers $i$ that satisfy the following: $i$ is in $S$ but $i+1$ is outside of $S$. However, one can check that if $\cal{N}$ is a numbering such that there are $R'> R$ integers $i$ such that $i$ is in $S$ and $i+1$ is not, then solving the puzzle with the numbering as $\cal{N}$ is impossible. Indeed, such a path would have to leave $S$ at least $R' > R$ times which means that an edge leaving $S$ would be repeated.

Comment: $\theta(n)$ means a function that grows proportionally to $n$, but I editted that out

Comment: ..as I can be more specific

Comment: We don't need to cite a theorem, since we know much more about the planar graph here. If $S$ is an $n \times \lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$ subgrid consisting of the leftmost $\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$ columns, then there are at most $n$ horizontal edges entering or leaving $s$, and at most $n-1$ diagonal edges. (We don't know the specific diagonal edges, but they come in crossing pairs and at most one can be present.) So a sharper bound of $R \le 2n-1$ holds.

Comment: Sure. I wasn't clear though if we were restricted to connecting vertices(in the grid) that were within Euclidean distance 2 e.g., whether we were allowed to connect vertices $\ge 2$ rows from each other, as long as arcs didn't cross.

Comment: In that case, I don't think this argument suffices. Consider: if we allow arbitrary (curved, but non-crossing) edges, then the path $1\to 2 \to 3 \to \dots \to n^2$ is always valid, since it is planar. Even though there is a set $S$ of size $n^2/2$ with at most $4n$ outgoing edges, it is constructed as a function of the permutation of $n^2$, so you can't go back and say "but the permutation is very unlikely to be such that it needs to leave $S$ at most $4n$ times".

Comment: I showed that for MOST pairs $G,\cal{N}$, where $G$ is the digraph between the vertices of the grid w no crossings, and $\cal{N}$ is a bijective numbering of the $n\times n$ grid from 1 to $n^2$, it is impossible to solve the resulting game. (Was this what was being asked?) You are correct in that I did not yet show the stronger statement, that for most $\cal{N}$ and *all* such $G$, it is impossible to solve the resulting game from $G,\cal{N}$. Although I do suspect even the stronger statement is true.

Comment: As far as I can tell, in the problem, we are given the numbering $\mathcal N$ and are free to pick $G$.

Comment: In that case, then given any bijective numbering $\cal{N}$ of $\{1,\ldots, n^2\}$ to the grid, there is a way to connect, for all $i$, the vertex numbered $i$ with the vertex numbered $i+1$ with polygonal curves $P_i$ that may have lots of bends but that do not cross (except at the endpoints i.e., $P_i$ intersects $P_{i-1}$ precisely at the vertex numbered $i$). I had to look this up though, it appears to be a deep result in recent research literature

Comment: Nah, a greedy argument works. If you draw arbitrary polygonal paths $P_1, \dots, P_i$ connecting $1,2,\dots,i+1$ in order, then it's always possible to draw $P_{i+1}$ because the complement of $P_1 \cup \dots \cup P_i$ is always path-connected.

Comment: Indeed @MishaLavrov  you are right. The planar graph we are trying to draw (with predetermined points for each vertex) is not merely only *planar*, but it is a *path*.  Using induction, we can show that as we extend the path to the next vertex, that the edges so drawn do not cross, implies that what we have drawn so far is a curve $C$ in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$  with no crossings, which means  $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} - C$ is connected, which means that we can extend $C$ to the next vertex (which is in  $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} - C$) without any crossings. Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible counterexample: Consider the board
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
3& 5& 7\\
1& 9& 2\\
4& 6& 8
\end{array}$$

Let the first row be set $A$, the second row be set $B$, and final row be set $C$.

First, notice that there can be at most $7$ edges crossing between $A$ and not-$A$ (you can check the possible cases for yourself), and similarly for $C$. So if you take a path from $1$ to $2$ that enters $A$, you use up $2$ of those crossings.

Since there has to be at least $6$ crossings going into $A$ that deal with hitting $3$ $5$ and $7$ (you have to go into $A$ before each number, and out of $A$ after each number), if you went into $A$ between $1$ and $2$, you wouldn't have enough edges to accomplish this. Thus, you cannot go into $A$ between $1$ and $2$. Same for $C$.

Thus, you have to start off your walk as $1\to9\to2$. But by doing this, you cut off the possibility of two of these edges between $A$ and not-$A$, leaving only $5$ possible edges, which isn't enough to hit everything in $A$.

Disclaimer: This answer was adapted from the linked reddit thread, and is not my own work.

Answer (score 0):

**ETA:** I just reread condition 4, cannot overlap edges. Without condition 4 this would be easy.

If I understand correctly, for such a path to exist, it suffices that edges are put in so that the resulting digraph is *strongly connected* w no crossing edges.

But this is always possible. Suppose that you can put do such a thing w an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ grid.
Let us now add the $n$-th row $(1,n), \ldots, (n,n)$ and $n$-th column $(n,n-1), \ldots, (n,1)$. Put an arc directed from $(i,n)$ and directed to $(i+1,n)$ for each $i$, and then put an arc directed from $(n,i)$ and directed into $(n,i-1)$ for each such $i$. Then put an arc directed from $(1,n)$ and directed into $(1,n-1)$,
and then from $(1,n-1)$ to $(1,n)$. Then the resulting graph on the $n \times n$ grid is strongly connected and has no connecting edges.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the connecting edges allowed can be chosen to run in one direction along the following edges:

[image]

except that only one of the crossing pairs of red lines may be used.

In this case it is easy to see that there can be at most five edges crossing from one layer to the next.

Now consider the following numbers placed in the grid:

[image]

It's clear that we will have used 5 connections into the bottom line by the time the trail reaches $6$. There will be no unused connections to get off the bottom layer to continue the path.

If you look at the solved puzzle in the answer, you can see something similar going on in the bottom layer of that puzzle. It only succeeds because there are no more numbers to get after $9$, but there is no way off that layer.

---

*Edit to add:* If a knight's move arrow is allowed, this could in principle give us one or two extra ways on and off the top and bottom layers. However this would come at the cost of breaking the links along the middle row shown here which would obviously mean an impossible extra requirement of links to the edge layers to navigate between those locations.

Comment: Looking at the original reddit post, "knight's move" edges are also allowed, though a similar argument holds in that case too.

Comment: Thanks, I can't see the reddit material. Added a remark to cover that case.